# jQuery validator - Check input field after leaving focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to check if the input field `inlineViewProvider_ONLYOFFICE_URL` starts with `https://` - after leaving focus of the field.

Here's my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

jQuery.validator.addMethod("httpsStarting", function (fieldInput, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || fieldInput.match("^https:\/\/");
}, "Field input should start with 'https://'.");

$('#inlineViewProvider_ONLYOFFICE_URL').validate({
    rules : { inlineViewProvider_ONLYOFFICE_URL: { httpsStarting: true } }
    });
});
```

If I put a `console : console.log($('#inlineViewProvider_ONLYOFFICE_URL'))` inside the `rules` value, the field value is printed to the console. But there is no error message if the input field doesn't start with `https://`.

Comment: 'cause you probably validated the empty field onReady, before you filled in any text. Move the validation to the onChange of the field

Comment: Did you read the validate plugin doc? `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` is per default enabled. ;)

Comment: Do you get a message if it _does_ start with `https://`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> there is no error message if the input field doesn't start with `https://`.

That's because you've apparently attached the `.validate()` method to the input field instead of the `form`.  In other words, you have not initialized the plugin.

```
$('#inlineViewProvider_ONLYOFFICE_URL').validate({ ....
```

To initialize the plugin to work on your `form`, you would attach `.validate()` to  a jQuery selector that represents the `<form>` *that contains* the `inlineViewProvider_ONLYOFFICE_URL` element.

```
$('#yourForm').validate({
    rules: { 
        inlineViewProvider_ONLYOFFICE_URL: { // <- this must represent the NAME attribute
            httpsStarting: true 
        } 
    }
});
```

Within the `rules` object, `inlineViewProvider_ONLYOFFICE_URL` must be the value of `name` attribute of this input element.

```
<form id="yourForm">
    <input type="text" name="inlineViewProvider_ONLYOFFICE_URL" />
    ....
</form>
```

Refer to [the Tag Wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info) for tips on proper usage.

---

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/namwLd37/**

Comment: Ah, i missed on that one. Cool, it helped me refresh the concept again in my head :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess:

The [jquery validation documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) about `.validate()` talks about

> Description: Validates the selected form.

Is your `#inlineViewProvider_ONLYOFFICE_URL` the form, or "just" an input field?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try the solution using [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead of [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

As per the documentation,

> **[test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)** returns Boolean e.g. `true` or `false`.

Whereas,

> **[match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)** returns an Array containing the matched results or `null` if there were no matches.

So `null` means `false` here.

This could be the reason IMO.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("httpsStarting", function (fieldInput, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^https?:\/\//i.test(fieldInput);
}, "Field input should start with 'https://'.");
```

This is the far i can suggest at this point by looking at the snippet. If it didn't work please let me know.

Comment: Mmmh, didn't work at all. I've also tried putting `onfocusout : true` in the `validate` method - didn't work. Actually the identifier from `validate` is set to one input field id - maybe I've to change that to the whole html form id.

Comment: Okay, try attaching `validate({})` to HTML form id instead of a particular form field.

Comment: The details are abstracted to me, is there anything else you can share as a clue??

Comment: Okay, form id didn't work either. If i put a `console.log("Foo")` inside the custom validator - there is NO console output. It seems that the custom validator won't be called at all.

Comment: `.match()` and `.test()` are both used within various methods [here](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js), so I don't think this is the real issue.  **OP needs to initialize the plugin or nothing will happen**.